# how to replace some characters of email address using * in python django

Tags: python, django, replace

I am new in `django`. I have problem in replacing the some characters of string. I want some characters hidden in email address. so i want to replace some characters of email using *.

email address: **demo.cipher@gmail.com**

I want email address like **demo*******@gmail.com**

I use `replace` function for replacing email address characters but isn't working.

```
x = demo.cipher@gmail.com
e = x.replace(x[5], '*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex.

```
import re

x = "demo.cipher@gmail.com"
print(re.sub(r"(?<=\.)(.*?)(?=@)", lambda x: "*"*len(x.group()), x))
```

**Output:**

```
demo.******@gmail.com
```

**Note:** In the above example if have replaced characters between `.` and `@` symbols using regex Lookbehind & Lookahead

Answer (score 0):

The most readable way in my opinion would be something along these lines.

```py
x = demo.cipher@gmail.com
e = x[:4] + "***@" + x.split("@")[-1]
```

Of course this solution uses some assumptions, which weren't clear in the question.

- the email address before `@` always has more than 4 characters
- you want to keep the first four characters visible
- showing how many letters were replaced is already some information you're providing to your reader, that shouldn't be necessary. Therefore I keep it to fixed three asterisks to make it slightly safer

If your action is time critical it would be important to look into timing these different ways.

Answer (score 0):

### Flexible solution

```
import math

user_email = 'demo.cipher@gmail.com'

email_split = user_email.split("@")

email_title = email_split[0]
email_domain = email_split[1]

line_count = max(math.ceil(len(email_title)/2), 1)
replaced_title = email_title.replace(email_title[line_count * -1:],'*' * line_count)
hidden_email = f'{replaced_title}@{email_domain}'
```

#### Output:

```
demo.cipher@gmail.com -> demo.******@gmail.com
demo@gmail.com -> de**@gmail.com
dr@gmail.com -> d*@gmail.com
```

### A simple solution

```
user_email = 'demo.cipher@gmail.com'
hidden_email  = ''.join([i if user_email.index(i)%3!=1 or i == '@' else '*' for i in user_email ])
```

#### Output:

```
demo.cipher@gmail.com -> d*mo*ci*h**@gmai**com
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.